# How to output a Python dictionary on which the keys are strings and values are lists of lists into an Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python, excel

I would like to take a Python dictionary on which the keys are strings and the values are lists of lists and output it into an Excel spreadsheet.

Basically, I want this:

I have a dict of the kind: dict1 = {"a":[list_a, list_b, ....], "b":[list_a1,list_b1,...]...}

I would like a spreadsheet on which the header are the keys, and each column below the header are the lists associated with the key.

Comment: You need to show an example of what your desired output spreadsheet would look like.  Your description is too vague.

Comment: Perhaps look into the `pandas` library for easy tabulation of data and writing to/from csv files (which can be viewed in Excel)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a CSV file and have excel load that.  Something like this:

```py
# create the header line if you want
print(",".join(list(dict1.keys())))

# output each row
for entry in dict1:
    print(",".join(list(dict1.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an excel based library like `openpyxl` or just write the data to csv and import that into excel. The second option I think will work better.

```
dict1 = {"a":[list_a, list_b, ....], "b":[list_a1,list_b1,...]...}

with open('out.csv','w+', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    # Write header
    writer.writerow(list(dict1.keys()))
    values = list(dict1.values())
    # Write each row
    for val in zip(*values):
        writer.writerow(val)
```